# Leaflet tooltip on icon after ajax call

Tags: leaflet

This leaflet fiddle produce what I want. eg. tooltip on custom marker

https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/juma/edit?html,output

I try to implement the same solution when I am fetching my data from an ajax call

I tried this, but it does not work, the console log is telling me Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…)

If i try to bindTooltip as text it works, but not when I try to reach the properties for each feature

```
    var myicon = L.icon({
                            iconUrl: 'assets/img/point.png',
                            iconSize: [8, 8]
                            });

    var pointlayer= L.geoJson(null,{
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: sandicon});
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.gid, {permanent:true,sticky:true}).openTooltip();
    }
    }).addTo(map);

    $.ajax({
        url: "root",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'getgjson',
        success: handledata
    });

    function handledata(data) {
        pointlayer.addData(data);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I bound mine on the pointToLayer function and it worked well.

```
    function getColor(d) {
    return  d == 'Cobra' ? '#000000':
            d == 'Cobra - Double' ? '#97bfc1':
            d == 'Colonial - Black' ? '#e48f21':
            d == 'Acorn - Black' ? '#841e0f':
            d == 'Acorn - Green' ? '#66953d':
            d == 'Shoebox - Black' ? '#901371':
            d == 'Flood - LED' ? '#00ffff':
            '#fdff1b';}
```

// Get GeoJSON data and create features.

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

```
    sites = L.geoJson(data, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor(feature.properties.Fixture_Ty),
            fillColor:  getColor(feature.properties.Fixture_Ty),
            fillOpacity: 0.8

            }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Pole_ID.toString());
        },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.on('click', function (e) {
                        // get coordinates from GeoJSON
                        var coords = e.target.feature.geometry.coordinates
                        //pass coords to function to create marker.
                        onMapClick(coords);
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I do when i just grap data from geojson. But it does not work when I get data from an ajax call. Are you using ajax to get your data?

I am first creating an empty layer and add data to with ajax (dont know how do to it otherwise)

Comment: I use the same basic code using JQuery to read the GeoJSON or a PHP web service spitting out JSON. I do not use the ajax plug in.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the code and see if i can get it to work on my data

Comment: Hmm I cannot for the life of me get it work. Really frustrating. It give me an error TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…)
But if it work for you im sure there must something else wrong